# mt65xx android phone usb drivers

Tags: android

I just need a link to download that driver . I tried everything but I couldn't find. I use windows 10 and everything I found is only for 7/8 . I made an app in android studio and I want to install it on my phone but without this driver is impossible.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this third party tool called [PdaNet](http://pdanet.co/). This will automatically install drivers fro your android device.

Comment: thanks man . it worked . after a day full of stress , I even contacted the company who made the phone and they said blah blah we don't have a driver blah blah . but now , it worked . thanks again . thanks very much

Comment: Glad it helped. This is what we(Stackoverflow members) do :)