# Debug android application directly from the device

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug an android application through my Nexus 5,
My computer wont detect the devices when I'm running the "adb  devices" commend from the cmd... 
I'm getting the following message "List of devices attached" and then an empty line.
i already have the recent USB drivers, my USB debugging option on my Nexus already on
what should i do
Thank you

Comment: Your driver is not installed correctly. Check my answer and use this tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443232/mt65xx-android-phone-usb-drivers/32443300#32443300

Answer (score 0):

First check if all proper drivers are installed.Then,

1.Goto the path where your adb is installed.In windows, its on ../sdk/platform-tools.
2.Kill and restart your server.
 run cmd : adb kill-server
 run cmd : adb start-server
3.Now you can see your devices using cmd : adb devices
4.If it shows here, run your application in debug mode and it will work.

Comment: I killed and restart the server it didn't  work either

Comment: Other things to check : 1.If usb debugging mode is enabled or not, check once again. 2.After you kill your server then try to plug-in your usb cable and start your server. 3.When you chose to run in debug mode check that you have properly selected your usb option. If all this things are done properly, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing other drivers , like "all usb driver" google it.